# How to search multiple word in message in kibana

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to search two keyword in kibana messages but whatever I do it does not return any result which I want.

I am trying to find logs which contains "ACTIVE" and "fill" keywords in the message field. When I search by "ACTIVE" it returns me result which contains both keyword.

Example:

```
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread:.....
.....
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
```

But when I try to search by both keyword it returns nothing. I tried those :

- message is ACTIVE, wrote fill in search field
- typed in search field: ACTIVE and fill, this returns all messages with "and"
- ```
  {
       "query": {
         "wilcard": {
           "message": "*ACTIVE*fill*"
         }
       }
     }
  ```

So what is the correct way to achieve this ?

Comment: Would a wildcard query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) work? Something like "ACTIVE*fill".

Comment: it did not work.I added my json in the main post

Comment: I don't know if the json you added is _exactly_ what you had set up as the filter (not just as the text search iirc), but if it is, I think you're missing one letter: "wilcard" should be "wildcard". Sorry if that's not helpful!

Comment: wildcard not wilcard

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna try this once.

```
   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "ACTIVE"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "fill"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
   }
```